# Is there any good academic references for Forex inefficiency?

Tags: fx, research, market-efficiency

I am PhD in computer science, and I am pretty much clueless where can I look for good journals or conferences for Forex that talked about its inefficiency.
Is there any good journals, conferences that has research papers covering this in a practical way? Or any particular research papers you would recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Market-maker, inventory control and
foreign exchange dynamics](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.431.295&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by Westerhoff and follow the references...

Comment: Here's a couple more modern papers you might like, with refs: [sharks and servers](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1889.en.pdf) and [high freq trading and the new market makers](https://papers.tinbergen.nl/11076.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the top 3 anomalies for FX (at low frequencies, i.e not HFT) are Carry, Momentum and Value, which are found in some markets other than FX as well. There is a *vast* literature on these.

For Carry I recommend a survey by Swinkels [Empirical Evidence on the Currency Carry Trade, 1900-2012](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2060207)

For Momentum in FX this link is good [Quantpedia: FX Momentum](http://quantpedia.com/Screener/Details/8)

"Value" in FX is generally equivalent with Relative Purchasing Power Parity, again Quantpedia has an overview [Quantpedia: FX Value - PPP](http://quantpedia.com/Screener/Details/9)

It is a huge area you ask about, too big to address really without knowing what you are trying to do. If you want a single overview of FX strategies a source also referenced in several of the above links is [Levich: A New Look at Currency Investing](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2571391)

One final warning: it is a lot more difficult to put into practice these ideas, and a lot more controversial how well they work, than these references make it seem.